# Unknown pattern character 'x', when using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, android-date

Im trying to format a `Date` to `String` using `SimpleDateFormat`, and the pattern im using is this one

> "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx"

but when reach this line

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx");
```

i get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'x' at
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePatternCharacter(SimpleDateFormat.java:323)
>   at
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePattern(SimpleDateFormat.java:312)
>   at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.(SimpleDateFormat.java:365) at
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat.(SimpleDateFormat.java:258)

the format im trying to achieve is 
"**2017-06-16T12:19:59.001+02:00**"

according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) this pattern should work
Whats wrong?

**EDIT**
To clarify, i tried with xxx and XXX

in case of XXX i get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'

Comment: You attached pattern with uppercase `X`, while documentation tells that it should be lowercase `x`. But then exception stack tells about lowercase `x` again. Can you please clarify that?

Comment: The 'X' for the timezone is relatively new feature in SimpleDateFormat. If you run it on an Android version that support only Java 6 then it won't work.

Comment: yes, but i tried both upper and lowercase.

Comment: @BalázsNemes whats the alternative?

Comment: You can use Z instead as the answer suggests it.

Comment: I really have no idea. This is a completely valid question. As, as oppose to Java SE, old version of Android don't support `X`. I have no idea why people wanna down vote this question for no reason. I'm gonna give this question an up-vote.

Answer (score 26):

### See Update below.

Unfortunately, regarding uppercase `X`, the documentation [was at the time of the question and this answer] wrong. Since the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) seems to have [changed significantly](https://web.archive.org/web/20160331172034/http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) regarding `x` and `X`, I'll go ahead and state here that right now, it says `X` (uppercase) is supported (since API level 1), but  `x` (lowercase) is not mentioned at all. The [docs used to](https://web.archive.org/web/20160331172034/http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) not mention `X` either.

A check of the [Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/cff1616/luni/src/main/java/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java) (see validateFormat()) shows that only the letters `GyMdkHmsSEDFwWahKzZLc` are recognized in that version, despite the docs' claim that `X` has been supported since API level 1. This explains why you're getting the `IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'`.

See [this bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65350732) for historical details.

Meanwhile, you'll have to find a workaround, which will vary depending on what kind of input you need to parse. E.g. [the OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44588864/423105).

## Update: X is available only from Nougat+.

The documentation has [now been fixed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65350732) to add a "Supported (API Levels)" column, which indicates that `X` is only supported starting from API level 24. Presumably the OP's `IllegalArgumentException` was due to testing the app on a pre-24 device, since the docs didn't say anything about supported API levels before.

Comment: I'm getting a warning about using "X" that claims my current min SDK would be 21 but it is 26. Really annoying...

Answer (score 20):

I believe I found the answer in an [issue at GitHub](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/1573#issuecomment-156947697):

> You are right, Android uses `ZZZZZ` instead to generate time zone like
>   `+01:00` (like `XXX` in Java). For now, could you try using the `ApiClient#setDatetimeFormat` method to customize the datetime format to
>   make it work in Android?
>
> Taking the petstore sample as an example:
>
> ```
> // import io.swagger.client.Configuration;
> // import io.swagger.client.ApiClient;
> // import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
>
> // Customize for the default ApiClient
> Configuration.getDefaultApiClient().setDatetimeFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"));
>
> // Customize for a new ApiClient
> ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
> apiClient.setDatetimeFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"));
> // Use the new ApiClient
> PetApi api = new PetApi(apiClient);
> api.getPetById(new Long(1));
> ```

Apparently, I have to use:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ
```

Comment: this is solved my issue. I'm using regex to check is it ISO8601: https://regex101.com/r/b3GJso/1, then override `parse(dateString)` to use normalize string in the [github url here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/1579/files#diff-2e2ac3bb2adb932ad8415782b16d2bfdR305-R312), otherwise just use `super.parse(dateString)`

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ");`

Comment: "ZZZZZ" doesn't help you much if you get a String with "-08:00".

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you need is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"` and yet it mentions a lowercase `x` in the exception. Looks like you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: i tried both upper and lowercase, ill edit question to clarify

Comment: also, on the examples they show on documentation they have "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00

Comment: You need to use UPPERCASE absolutely. Like I am mentioning. What is the exception when you use the UPPERCASE `X`?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody will look here for an answer how to format string with pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"` for devices with API lower than 24.

Use Java DateTimeFormatter and OffsetDateTime since it does not require providing input pattern like SimpleDateFormat

Java code :

```
 public static String formatISO8601String(String string) {
        DateTimeFormatter desiredFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(string);
        return dateTime.format(desiredFormat);
    }
```

Kotlin code :

```
fun formatISO8601String(string: String): String {
        val desiredFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        val dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(string)
        return dateTime.format(desiredFormat)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you are looking for "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Change date format to

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"); 
or

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

this may be help you

Comment: `Z` is RFC-style time zone, while another one is ISO-style time zone. I don't think these'll work in general (they might for some special cases).

Comment: you can refer https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: where small z used for general time zone

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.UK);
String formattedDate = sdf.format(new Date());

Comment: And this format could parse "2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00"? (Can't try at the moment)?