# SimpleDateFormat.parse() ignoring timezone?

Tags: android, simpledateformat, timezone-offset, datetime-parsing

I am trying to parse date string with timezone using this code for tests:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZZZZ", Locale.US);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(sdf.parse("2017-07-26T06:00-06:00"));
int offset = calendar.getTimeZone().getRawOffset();
```

I am trying to change timezone from `-06` to `+09`, but `offset` always contains `10800000`.

How to parse date with timezone correctly (I need time and timezone both)?

Comment: Yes, I am. I get it from remote server and can't change it. I just need to parse it.

Comment: Why? It completely ok and just doesn't contains a seconds.

Comment: `-06:00` - that is not a time. That is timezone. It can be `-09:00` or `+05:00` or something like this.

Comment: Sure I read it before... Possibly you mean that I have to use `XXX` instead of `ZZZZZ`. But it doesn't works. If you are interested you can launch code from question or read here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28373610/1393280

Comment: It doesn't work (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'). Please read about it by link above.

Comment: It doesn't work with `.SSSZ` or `.Z`, with dot or without it. `S` - that is milliseconds, in my date it absent. Yes, I can remove timezone. But I need to get timezone. I need to get time with timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: `-06:00` is an [offset, not a timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) - those 2 concepts are related, but they are different things (more on that below).

---

The problem with `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar` is that they use the system's default timezone, so even though you parse a date with a different offset (like `-06:00`), the resulting `Calendar` will have the default timezone (you can check what zone is by calling `TimeZone.getDefault()`).

That's just one of the many [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api) of this old API.

Fortunately, there's a better alternative, if you don't mind adding a dependency to your project (in this case, I think it's totally worth it). In Android you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to make it work (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

To work with offsets, you can use the `org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime` class:

```
// parse the String
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-07-26T06:00-06:00");
```

This will parse all the fields correctly (date/time and offset). To get the offset value, similar to `calendar.getTimeZone().getRawOffset()`, you can do:

```
// get offset in milliseconds
int totalSeconds = odt.getOffset().getTotalSeconds() * 1000;
```

I had to multiply by 1000 because `calendar` returns the value in milliseconds, but `ZoneOffset` returns in seconds.

To convert this to another offset (`+09:00`), it's straightforward:

```
// convert to +09:00 offset
OffsetDateTime other = odt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(9));
```

---

As I said, timezone and offset are different things:

- offset is the difference from [**UTC**](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html): `-06:00` means "6 hours behind UTC" and `+09:00` means "9 hours ahead UTC"
- timezone is a set of all the different offsets that a region had, has and will have during its history (and also when those changes occur). The most common cases are [Daylight Saving Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/) shifts, when clocks change 1 hour back or forward in a certain region. All these rules about when to change (and what's the offset before and after the change) are encapsulated by the timezone concept.

So, the code above works fine if you're working with offsets and wants to convert to a different one. But if you want to work with a timezone, you must convert the `OffsetDateTime` to a `ZonedDateTime`:

```
// convert to a timezone
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo"));
// get the offset
totalSeconds = zdt.getOffset().getTotalSeconds() * 1000;
```

The `getOffset()` method above will check the history of the specified timezone and get the offset that was active in that corresponding instant (so, if you take a date during DST, for example, the offset (and also date and time) will be adjusted accordingly).

The API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

You can also use the system's default timezone with `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, but this can be changed without notice, even at runtime, so it's better to explicity use a specific one.